# Why derived table is updatable in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have just found that derived table is updatable in oracle. When updating a derived table, the table it based is updated as a result.

Example `UPDATE (SELECT * FROM T where T.col1='val1') as D SET D.col2 ='some_val'`

After the example sql executed, table T would be updated.

I don't understand why Oracle support this feature.

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681248/delete-update-with-derived-tables) described, in mysql, derived table is not updatable.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? The question is rather why MySQL says it isn't.

Comment: I‘m updating a derived table, it should be a temporary table. But Oracle updated the base table, so I got surprised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be instructive to view [Codd's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules) for relational databases.

Rule 7 is:

> Rule 7: High-level insert, update, and delete:
>
> The capability of handling a base relation or a **derived relation** as a single operand applies not only to the retrieval of data but also to the insertion, update and deletion of data.

**My emphasis** - and note that an important aspect that many people get wrong with relational databases is what the word "relation" or "relational" mean - *relations* are what are called *tables* in SQL. Many people *assume* that the "relational" in relational databases is the same sort of thing as a relationship in an Entity Relationship Model - and therefore leap to assuming that relational somehow relates to e.g. Foreign Keys.

Now, I'm not saying that SQL, either as embodied in the ANSI standard, or as embodied in any particular product is a complete implementation of Codd's Rules (indeed, Rule 6 is quite problematic), but there are at least *attempts* to implement them in some products.