# How to fix my query ? I get a message "the target table is not updatable"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the `new_table` with the query below.

Unfortunately I get a warning `The target table n2 of the UPDATE is not updatable`. How can I fix this?

```
UPDATE new_table n 
       JOIN (SELECT hash, 
                    visits, 
                    first_visit, 
                    last_visit, 
                    Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) AS date_diff, 
                    ( Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) / visits ) AS diafora 
             FROM   new_table 
             WHERE  Date(first_visit) >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 15 day) 
                    AND Date(last_visit) >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
                    AND visits > 1 
             HAVING date_diff > 0) AS n2 
         ON n2.hash = n.hash 
SET    n.diafora = n2.visits_frequency
```

**UPDATE**

the `visits_frequency` is a column in the new_table. The `diafora` is calculated and the `visits_frequence` must take its value.

Comment: You cannot update content of a derived table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete, Update with derived tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681248/delete-update-with-derived-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no visits_frequency field on n2 table. Where is this field coming from? Is it calculated or maybe you forgot it in the select? If it comes from select, you could try:

```
UPDATE new_table n 
       JOIN (SELECT hash, 
                    visits, 
                    visits_frequency,
                    first_visit, 
                    last_visit, 
                    Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) AS date_diff, 
                    ( Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) / visits ) AS diafora 
             FROM   new_table 
             WHERE  Date(first_visit) >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 15 day) 
                    AND Date(last_visit) >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
                    AND visits > 1 
             HAVING date_diff > 0) AS n2 
         ON n.hash = n2.hash 
SET    n.diafora = n2.visits_frequency
```

---

Considering you want n.visit_frequency to take the value of n2.diafora calculation, try the following:

```
UPDATE new_table n 
       JOIN (SELECT hash, 
                    visits, 
                    visits_frequency,
                    first_visit, 
                    last_visit, 
                    Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) AS date_diff, 
                    ( Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) / visits ) AS diafora 
             FROM   new_table 
             WHERE  Date(first_visit) >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 15 day) 
                    AND Date(last_visit) >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
                    AND visits > 1 
             HAVING date_diff > 0) AS n2 
         ON n.hash = n2.hash 
SET    n.visits_frequency = n2.diafora
```

Comment: Why would swapping the order of values in the `ON` clause change anything?

Comment: The order of tables in the ON conditions does not matter, only the fact that this is a derived table. (When it comes to pure joins, then the only thing what matters is the order of tables in the FROM list).

Comment: Hi the `visits_frequency` is a column in the `new_table`. The `diafora` is calculated and the `visits_frequence` must take its value

Comment: @Pashiamas I've updated the answer with something you can try. Changed just the last line.